# Multidimensional array of images

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am having troubles with my multidimensional array. There are no errors, but the images are not appearing. I don't know why. please help

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><script src="kinetic.js"></script></head>
<body>
<div id="canvas" align="center">
    <span id="timer"></span>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script>
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 850,
            height: 650
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

        var image = [];
        var img = [];

        var images = [
            ["1.png","2.png","3.png","4.png"]
        ];
```

this is the part where I am having problems:

```
        for (var a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
            img[a] = new Image();
            img.src = images[0][a];
            img.onload = function(){
                image[a] = new Kinetic.Image({
                    x: Math.floor(Math.random()*400),
                    y: Math.floor(Math.random()*400),
                    image: img[a],
                    width: 500,
                    height: 500
                });
                layer.add(image[a]);
                image[a].draw();
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the stray `enter code here` line for, the line after `layer` is declared? That is not valid syntax. Is that in your actual code, or was that just for the post here?

Comment: oops that wasn't in the code